# RxJS: How can I do an "if" with Observables?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

Say I have two observables and one I want to listen on changes in one observable, if the other on matches a certain condition. I tried it with `zip` but it seems I will only be notified, if *both*  observables change, but I want to be notified for every change on the one observable, if the condition of the other one is true.

What I tried:

```
var firstState = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(undefined);
var secondState = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(undefined);

Rx.Observable.zip(firstState, secondState, function (first, second) {
  return {
    first: first,
    second: second
  }
}).filter(function (value) {
  return value.first !== undefined;
}).subscribe(function (value) {
  // do something with value.second
});
```

I noticed there is an `Rx.Observable.if`, but I couldn't got it to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [pausable](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/pausable.md):

```
secondState
    .pausable(firstState.map(function (s) { return s !== undefined; }))
    .subscribe(function (second) {
        // only occurs when first is truthy
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Zip literally means so. It zips up taking corresponding elements in two different sequence. What you are trying to achieve can be done in many different ways.

```js
firstState.combineLatest(secondState, function(f, d) { 
    return f == 10 && d > 10;
}).filter(function(val) { return val })
  .subscribe(function(v) { console.log(v); });

firstState.onNext(10);
secondState.onNext(20);
```

This is one of the ways.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I accepted Brandons answer, because it matches my problem even better.