# RxJs alternate for if then else statement

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

What is the best way to write following code in RxJs. Assuming getSomethingFromDb( ) returns an observable. **Note: I do not want to use IF from my RXJS code**

```
let something:any = getSomethingFromDatabsae( )

if(<value inside something observable is not undefined>){
   doThis( );
} else {
   doThat( );
}
```

**Edit: I am going to make my question more interesting. What if my code is more complex like this, how to implement this without using if statements in RxJS. ( more declartively )**

```
let observable:any = getSomethingFromDatabsae( )

if(<value inside observable is not undefined>){
   doThis( );
} else if(<value inside observable is "one">) {
   doFirstThing( );
}else if(<value inside observable is "two">) {
   doSecondThing( );
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315026/rxjs-how-can-i-do-an-if-with-observables

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32594357/rxjs-modeling-if-else-control-structures-with-observables-operators

Answer (score 0):

I thought what are you looking for is the operator 'Partition '

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-partition

provide the condition, and you will get the 'pass' stream and the 'fail' stream