# Wait for a stream before invoking another stream

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

How do I wait for one stream (say, `StreamA`) to return non-null value and then invoke `StreamB` subscribe function. I'm not particularly interested in `StreamA`'s value. In turn, I am trying to get `StreamB`'s value which might have been updated before the StreamA returned non-null value, and might not have any new events.

I tried, *pausable*, by looking at this: [RxJS: How can I do an "if" with Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28315026/rxjs-how-can-i-do-an-if-with-observables), but unfortunately could not get it to work. This is because, there are no exported class `pausable`, rxjs v 5.0.0-beta.6.

This is how far, I've come up with, as per the answer.

export class AuthService {
      userModel: FirebaseListObservable = this.af.database.list(`/users`);
      constructor(private af: AngularFire) {

```
    var user = this.currentAuthor();
    var userStream = user;

    this.af.auth.flatMap((d) => { console.log(d);return this.userModel.publishReplay(1); });

    this.userModel
      .subscribe((data) => {
        var flag = false;
        data.forEach((item) => {
          if (item.$key && item.$key === user.uid) {
            flag = true;
            return;
          }
        });

        if (flag) {
          console.log('hello');
        } else {
          this.userModel.push({
              firstName: user.auth.displayName.substr(0, user.auth.displayName.lastIndexOf(' ')),
              lastName: user.auth.displayName.substr(user.auth.displayName.lastIndexOf(' '), user.auth.displayName.length),
              displayPic: user.auth.photoURL,
              provider: user.provider,
              uid: user.uid
            }
          );
        }
      })
  }
  public currentAuthor():FirebaseAuthState  {
    return this.af.auth.getAuth();
  }
```

Hope, I can make myself clear. Even I am getting confused now. :p.

I am new to rxjs and reactive programming. And, any help will be appreciated.

And, btw, thanks for stopping by. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose by `plausible` you mean `pausable`? I am not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve here (control flow?). However, if you want streamB value after streamA produces a value, then you can use `flatMap`.

`streamA.flatMapLatest(function (_){return streamB})`

That should give you, anytime `streamA` emits, the values emitted after that time by `streamB`.

If you want values including the last one B emitted prior to that time, you can use `streamBB = streamB.publishReplay(1)` and

`streamA.flatMapLatest(function (_){return streamBB})`

Haven't tested it, so keep me updated if that works.

Comment: I've added the code, to make things a little clearer to you. (Hope that helps). Also, with the above code I am getting the following error in TS Compiler.

`Property 'publishReplay' does not exist on type 'FirebaseListObservable<any[]>'.`

Comment: well, you need to have a look at your types. In the `flatMapLatest` you will see that it is an observable which is returned. So check that your `FirebaseListObservable` is indeed an observable. You can find `publishReplay` here `http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html`, so it should definitely be part of Rxjs v5.

Comment: `flatMapLatest` should be `switchMap` in RxJS 5